# Pasar proyecto de Visual Studio a una versión más reciente (2015)

Tags: visual-studio

Como pasar un proyecto de Visual Studio a una versión más reciente 2015 pero no se la versión del proyecto anterior.
Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Si tratas de abrir el proyecto con VS2015 debería intentar actualizarlo. A partir de ahí, si te da problemas, habrá que revisarlos.

Comment: Yo lo he hecho abriendo el ejecutable con block de notas y modifico la version que esta ahi solo no recuerdo que extención es el archivo

Comment: Esque cuando intento abrir el proyecto que tiene la version inferiror a mi VS me marca error diciendome que uno o mas componentes no fueron cargados

Comment: Te marca eso y te abre una ventana en el navegador? has tratado despues de que abre el navegador?

Comment: Podrias copiar el error que te da cuando lo abris